# How does one find non-conformance to a spec when both the RTL'ers and the verification engineers miss a particular spec feature?

Tags: verilog, specman, asic

I have some questions regarding IP verification.

Suppose if a particular design/functionality from an IP specification is missed both in the RTL and the verification plan (Coverage points), how would you identify this bug?

Since it hasn't been implemented in RTL(missed from SPEC), we cannot identify from code coverage.

Please throw some light on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone should be comparing the verification plan against the top-level IP specification.  For each point in the spec, the question "how do we show we met this requirement?" needs a good answer.

(If the feature in question is not in there, then the top-level spec needs fixing!)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a feature list and write your tests against that.

Answer (score 0):

The design and testplan reviews generally involve the comparison of the IP specification to said designs and testplans. The IP spec writer is usually present, as well, and can identify points in the spec that are not covered.